# Perl Split Binary Data into Chunks with Unpack

Tags: perl, binary, chunked-encoding, unpack, chunked

I'm using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` to write an HTTP response.

The response is split into pieces via the following:

```
my $template = "a$buffer_size" x int(length($response)/$buffer_size) . 'a*';

foreach my $buffer (unpack $template, $response){
    ...
}
```

This works fine when the content type is `text/html`, but it is corrupting binary data, such as `application/pdf`.

Can `unpack` be used to split binary data into equal lengths?

Comment: When you say that the content type is causing the corruption, have you confirmed that by trying to access the same data, send with different MIME types?

Comment: Also, what is the nature of the corruption?

Comment: @Dancrumb the "corruption" is that the file is incorrectly flagged as UTF-8 and not ANSI. Strange thing is if I simulate `unpack` with `grep {/\S/} split /(.{$buffer_size})/`, everything is fine. Also, the `unpack` logic is OK if done at the command line (i.e., not via mod_perl or ActiveState PerlEx).

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10850622/edit) to provide your [full code and input data](http://sscce.org). When you just paraphrase parts of it in English prose, it is impossible to help you because we are not able to [reproduce the problem](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html#showmehow).

Comment: Using the Plack streaming interface for chunked encoding: http://codepad.org/531qBASm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure why `unpack` is failing in this context, but I stumbled upon a solution.

If I manipulate the response with an in-memory file, `unpack` works correctly:

```
my $resp;
open (my $fh, '>', \$resp);
my $fh_old = select($fh);
print $response;
close $fh;
select($fh_old);
$response = $resp;
```

Any insight into why this works?

Comment: Finally tracked down the root of the problem. The PDF file was being created on-the-fly from a unicode database. I was converting wide characters into `cp1252` to match `WinAnsiEncoding` of the font object. Perl switched into `utf8` mode when it encountered a wide character. This caused `unpack` to fail since it was set to operate in `ascii` mode.

Answer (score 0):

That works perfectly fine with binary data. The problem is elsewhere. (Did you `binmode` all relevant handles?)